File conversion to mp3 returning failure everytime using flutter package ffmpeg_kit_flutter
I am trying to convert a .wav audio file generated from a flutter's text to speech package - "flutter_tts" to mp3 file but it is failing everytime.
I have written the below code for file conversion. I have imported the package ffmpeg_kit_flutter. It doesnt even show why the conversion is failing.
I have looked up in stackoverflow and other sites but could not find any relevant solutions. I am using vscode as editor. I have attached flutter doctor output below as well. Could anyone please guide me? Let me know if you need more information.
List<String> command = [
              '-i', '$filePath/998tts.wav',
              '-c:a', 'mp3',
              '$filePath/998.mp3'
            ];

 await FFmpegKitConfig.enableLogs();
            FFmpegKitConfig.enableLogCallback((log) =>print('FFmpeg log: $log'));        
          FFmpegSession result = await FFmpegKit.executeWithArguments(command);
          dynamic resultcode = await result.getReturnCode();
          dynamic resultlogs = await result.getLogsAsString();
          // FFmpegKitConfig.setLogLevel(logLevel)
          if(ReturnCode.isSuccess(resultcode)){
          print("file saved after conversion at $filePath/998.mp3 and result : Success and logs : $resultlogs");
          }
          else{
            print("Result : failure and logs : $resultlogs");
          }

Flutter doctor output:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3296], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9.5)
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++"
workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.89.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


Edit: Attaching error logs:
I/flutter (25865): Loading ffmpeg-kit-flutter.
D/ffmpeg-kit-flutter(25865): FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.flutter.FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin@a5d9788 started listening to events on io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler$EventSinkImplementation@4cfb5f2.
I/flutter (25865): Loaded ffmpeg-kit-flutter-android-audio-arm64-v8a-6.0.3.
I/flutter (25865): Result : failure and logs : ffmpeg version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
I/flutter (25865):   built with Android (7155654, based on r399163b1) clang version 11.0.5 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 87f1315dfbea7c137aa2e6d362dbb457e388158d)

I/flutter (25865):   configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile 


Please mention your error logs.

I have attached the error logs above from the output. It doesnt seem to say what is the cause of the failures. Is there any other place where i can collect the error logs?

I don't understand which type of file you are trying to convert to mp3. In your provided code, I can see that you are providing audioFilePath as a file input and you are trying to convert it. Can you be more specific about which type of file you are trying to convert.?

I am creating a app which can record audio or use text to speech to generate the audio. I'm trying to upload this mp3 file to a website  and try to play it there. The recorded audio plays properly in the website, but the text to speech audio is not playing. I am able to access the text to speech audio file in my mobile and play it there, but it doesnt play in the website. I thought of using FFMPEG flutter package for file type conversion as I thought there might be issue in file type. It is able to convert the file occasionally and the converted mp3 file is playing in the website.... contd...

contd....  But the file conversion fails most of the time with the error " Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!  Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026." Also FFMPEG flutter package is outdated and not supported anymore, so i used the latest ffmpeg_kit_flutter package. Using this package, the file conversion fails everytime. The error logs doesnt even properly say why it fails. I have attached the error logs i found in the above "edit".

You can convert an audio file to MP3 using ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio instead of ffmpeg_kit_flutter.
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio enables external libraries that support MP3.
https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit?tab=readme-ov-file#9-packages
Here is a minimal code snippet.
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio/ffmpeg_kit.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio/return_code.dart';

Future<bool> ffmpeg({
  required String inputPath,
  required String outputPath,
}) async {
  final session = await FFmpegKit.execute('-y -i $inputPath $outputPath');
  final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
  return ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode);
}

Usage
await ffmpeg(
  inputPath: '/path/to/input.wav',
  outputPath: '/path/to/output.mp3',
);

